# How do i create a foreach loop using java

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a List for each and i don't know what to do so. what i'm trying to do is create a list.add() but i wanna have a min year to max year so like start at 1980 to 2014 but i don't wanna have to create all the list so i'm trying find help with doing it with a foreach loop.

Comment: I would suggest going through the Java language tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Probably easier to use a good old-fashioned `for` loop than a `foreach`.  It could start with `for (int year = 1980; year <= 2014; year++){`

Comment: You could use `IntStream.range(1980,2015)` (start is inclusive, but end is exclusive).  Then you can call `forEach` on it, or `collect` to get a List.  And more...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the loop with an array then use foreach loop for each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are saying is that you are trying to create a list with values from `x` to `y` so in your case, `1980` to `2014`. And you don't want to have to individually add each one, i.e.

```
list.add(1980);
list.add(1981);
list.add(1982);
...
```

What you can do is create an `IntStream` for a range of values and then add all of them to the list.

Like this,

```
List<Integer> years = IntStream.rangeClosed(1980, 2014).boxed().toList();
```

Note: `IntStream.rangeClosed(x, y)` will be inclusive to upper and lower bounds, meaning it will include all values from `x` to `y`, including `x` and `y`.

Comment: The OP speaks about for-each loop, not Stream API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you bother searching for your answer first?

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

```
for (int x = 1980; x <= 2014; x++) {
    list.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
 
public class ForEachInteration {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
 
        collection.add("zero");
        collection.add("one");
        collection.add("two");
 
        // for-each loop
        for (String s : collection) {
        System.out.println("value= " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

[here](https://knowm.org/iterating-through-a-collection-in-java/).

Remarks:

- it's syntactically a `for`
- it's semantically a foreach